# Comparison of the two following rectifier configurations

Tags: operational-amplifier, rectifier

Could anyone tell me the limitations of each of the two following full-wave rectifier configurations? Since the first one does the job, why a more complex design is better? Thank you.[image]

Comment: You may want to fix the pin numbers on the first diagram, or just remove them.

Answer (score 7):

In each case, look at what happens when the first stage cuts off.

In the simpler circuit, the first opamp's output hits the negative supply rail and stays there until the input goes negative again. Then it slowly comes out of saturation and ramps up at its slew rate until finally the diode starts conducting again.

In the second circuit, D2 keeps it out of saturation and the output only has to transition across 2 diode drops to start conducting again.

This will impact its accuracy for high frequency inputs.

If you're only rectifying low frequency signals, or the opamp behaves well in saturation and has a high slew rate, the first circuit is OK, but if you need accuracy on high frequency signals with a low cost opamp, the second may meet your goals more economically.

Comment: @glen_geek : no, they are both full wave rectifiers. Consider a positive input : D4 is reverse biased. Assume a normal opamp (where the inputs remain high impedance for large differential inputs). The first circuit reduces to a unity gain buffer U6 fed from 400 kilohms (R9+R11). Negative inputs you can work out yourself.

Comment: D'oh! -you're right - both are full-wave, and your caution about slow slewing on the first is its primary fault. Have removed my comment.